# How to access system clipboard from a chroot environment?

Tags: linux, vim, chroot

I am running `vim` in `chroot` but I don't seem to have access to the host system's clipboard even if I do <kbd>"+p</kbd>. It works in the host system's `vim`.

Is it possible to make the `chroot` environment recognize the host systems clipboard especially with `vim`?

Comment: Vim needs the X server in order to access the clipboard; you may need to pass `.Xauthority` into the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a problem with X server. [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Change_root) on chroot explains how this can be done.

Specifically:

`xhost +local:`

Make sure that `vim` is compiled with `+clipboard` option.